# CS0308 Marshal.SizeOf<> error, how do I fix that?

Tags: c#

I have error in this code:

```
            intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION>(object_BASIC_INFORMATION));
            Win32API.NtQueryObject(zero, 0, intPtr, Marshal.SizeOf<Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION>(object_BASIC_INFORMATION), ref num);
            object_BASIC_INFORMATION = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(intPtr, object_BASIC_INFORMATION.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtr);
            intPtr2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(object_BASIC_INFORMATION.TypeInformationLength);
            num = object_BASIC_INFORMATION.TypeInformationLength;
```

This line:

```
intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION>(object_BASIC_INFORMATION));
```

What am I doing wrong?

OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION:

```
        public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
    {
        public int Attributes;
        public int GrantedAccess;
        public int HandleCount;
        public int PointerCount;
        public int PagedPoolUsage;
        public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
        public int Reserved1;
        public int Reserved2;
        public int Reserved3;
        public int NameInformationLength;
        public int TypeInformationLength;
        public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
    }
```

Error:

> CS0308  C# The non-generic method cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Please read the error message: "_The non-generic method cannot be used with type arguments_". It says that the method is non-generic. So, don't try to use it as if it were a generic method. (Note that the generic version of Marshal.SizeOf was introduced with .NET 4.5.1. If you are targetting an older .NET version in your project, the generic version of that method is not available)

Comment: @HansPassant, there is a generic overload that does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf__1___0_